# Appending datasets by matched variables

Tags: append, stata

I have to append three datasets named `A`, `B` and `C` that contain data for various years (for example, `1990, 1991...2014`).

The problem is that not all datasets contain all the survey years and therefore the unmatched years need to be dropped manually before appending.

I would like to know if there is any way to append three (or more) datasets that will keep only the matched variables across the datasets (years in this case).

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful at all?

Comment: Yes it does the trick. Thanks so much for sharing the code, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following toy example:

```
clear

input year var
1995 0
1996 1
1997 2
1998 3 
1999 4
2000 5
end

save data1, replace

clear

input year var
1995 6
1996 9
1998 7 
1999 8
2000 9
end

save data2, replace

clear

input year var
1995 10
1996 11
1997 12
2000 13
end

save data3, replace
```

There is no option that will force `append` to do what you want, but you can do the following:

```
use data1, clear

append using data2 data3
duplicates tag year, generate(tag)

sort year
list

     +------------------+
     | year   var   tag |
     |------------------|
  1. | 1995     0     2 |
  2. | 1995     6     2 |
  3. | 1995    10     2 |
  4. | 1996     9     2 |
  5. | 1996     1     2 |
     |------------------|
  6. | 1996    11     2 |
  7. | 1997     2     1 |
  8. | 1997    12     1 |
  9. | 1998     7     1 |
 10. | 1998     3     1 |
     |------------------|
 11. | 1999     8     1 |
 12. | 1999     4     1 |
 13. | 2000    13     2 |
 14. | 2000     5     2 |
 15. | 2000     9     2 |
     +------------------+

drop if tag == 1
list

     +------------------+
     | year   var   tag |
     |------------------|
  1. | 1995     0     2 |
  2. | 1995     6     2 |
  3. | 1995    10     2 |
  4. | 1996     9     2 |
  5. | 1996     1     2 |
     |------------------|
  6. | 1996    11     2 |
  7. | 2000    13     2 |
  8. | 2000     5     2 |
  9. | 2000     9     2 |
     +------------------+
```

You can also further generalize this approach by finding the maximum value of the variable `tag` and keeping all observations with that value:

```
summarize tag
keep if tag == `r(max)'
```